# Site updates are live!

Tags: discussion, design

A majority of the changes are not be visible; these tweaks go along with recent updates that were made to Stack Overflow:

- We have updated the site's CSS to a newly refactored LESS system, so that it's easier for us to fix SE network CSS bugs globally and launch new features in the future.
- We've updated most of the graphics to SVG for retina support, and adjusted the header layout to make it consistent with the majority of other network sites.
- We have fixed a LOT of obscure bugs that arose when new features were not thoroughly tested across the entire network.
- We've launched the new user profile.

Visually it should "feel" the same as the old site with slight layout adjustments.

This update should retro-actively fix most of the old design bugs. If you see any new bugs, or old ones not yet fixed, please post an answer here to let us know!

Comment: I really like the redesign.

Comment: The image on the header of the page is OK (looks clearer), but in my browser (firefox) the font used in the body of the Questions (and Answers) looks HORRIBLE ... it looks like a boldface font ?!?; and also the monospace font used in the editing window is worst than the old one (Courier?).  Furthermore the sizes of the fonts in the whole page (e.g. in the right column) seem smaller, so the page is less readable with the default zoom of the browser. I know that it is an annoying feedback for you, but if I had a button "switch back to the old look" I would click it :-)

Comment: thx for the effort on something that has been unchanging for years. great sites continually incorporate tweaks/ improvements in layout, others dont. (for comparison think one of the most leading/ best of all is netflix, one of the worst is amazon.) hopefully you can incorporate feedback. some advance notice would have been helpful.

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi would you mind posting a screen capture of what you're seeing as an answer along with your browser specs so that I can investigate? Thanks!

Comment: @KurtisBeavers: done!

Comment: @KurtisBeavers: is there any news?

Comment: @KurtisBeavers: I just looked to the mathoverflow site after the css restyle ... the font used there (for Questions and Answers) is much better than the new one of cstheory ... (but the old cstheory one is still better).  Of course, this is MY opinion :-)

Comment: I like the new looks! But: the tape content in that bordure is ... boring. What a wasted opportunity for an inside joke!

Answer (score 2):

We're pushing a change to the body font to match the font stack of Math Overflow. It should go live during our next production build (some time today or tomorrow.) Thanks.

Comment: Good job! A curiosity, is the current font/size the same as the older one? (I'm not 100% sure but looking at the picture, it seems a little bit different from the current one)

Answer (score 1):

As requested by Kurtis in the comment above, 4 snapshot of the Q&A before and after the restyle.

Old style question (from Wayback, so no Mathjax rendering):

[image]

New style question; **IMO** the font seems boldface, also you can notice the smaller size for the title font, and score font (also other boxes look smaller):

[image]

Old style Answer:

[image]

New style answer:

[image]

My browser is Firefox 40.0.3 on Windows (default configuration)